# Transmitting a JSON-Object to a new HTML side

Tags: html, json, object

Hello guys i have a big problem, which i somehow cant fix. I am having some JSON- Objects which i am giving out with a table, this part works perfectly fine. But than i would like to have a button or link that posts one of this JSON- Objects (the ID) to a new .html page. In this new .html page i would like to use the ID in Javascript code.
Does anybody know if there is a way how i can accomplish this and if yes how can i do it?
I tried to post it via the php _get methode but it just doesnt work it tells me that there is an " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

My JS-Code looks like this:

function dataRequest() {

```
    var output = $('#output').text('Loading data...');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test/html/getmeineFahrten.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){

            output.empty();

            var ort ='<table border="dashed" width="30%">'
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var ServerDatum = item.abfahrt
            var Datumonly = ServerDatum.substring(0,4) + ServerDatum.substring(5,7) + ServerDatum.substring(8,10);
            var calcDatum = Datum - Datumonly
            if(item.user_user_id == userID){
            if(calcDatum < 0){
            ort += '<tr>'+'<td>'+item.abfahrt+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+item.rueckfahrt+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+item.StartOrt+'</td>'
            + '<td>'+item.Zielort+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<form action="http://test/html/meineFahrten_Karte.html?FahrtenID= + item.fahrten_id" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Karte">'+'</form>'+'</td>'+'</tr>';

            }}
            });
            ort +='</table>';
            output.append(ort);
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Something went wrong. Would you like to retry?',
                yourCallback,
               'Error',
                'No,Yes'
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access URL parameters  unless you create your own function to do so. Unfortunately, there is no native function for this yet, however, user Quentin answers this question in greater detail and provides a function for getting URL parameters.

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)